# If $A^2=B^2=I$, then what are the eigenvalues of $AB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$. If $A^2=B^2=I$, then what are the eigenvalues of $AB$?
I know that if the eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$ are the same, then the eigenvalues of $AB$ are $+1$ and$-1$. What should I do in general case?

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970409/possible-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-ab?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, your question is closely related to [Possible eigenvalues of a matrix $AB$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970409/possible-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-ab?rq=1) . In fact, [Omnomnomnom's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/970428) to that question is also applicable here. But for sake of having an answer, I'll write one below.

First, the spectrum of $AB$ (over $\mathbb C$) must be of the form $\{z, \frac1z\}$. Why? From $A^2=B^2=I$, we get $AABB=I$. Therefore $ABBA=I$, i.e. $(AB)^{-1}=BA$, which is similar to $AB$ because $BA=B(AB)B^{-1}$. So, $(AB)^{-1}$ is similar to $AB$. Hence the eigenvalues of $AB$ occur in reciprocal pairs.

Since nonreal eigenvalues of a real matrix must occur in conjugate pairs, it follows that if the eigenvalues of $AB$ happen to be nonreal, they must also have unit moduli.

We now claim that for every nonzero number $x$ and every complex number $z$ with unit modulus, each of $\{x, \frac1x\}$ and $\{z, \frac1z\}$ is the spectrum of some $AB$ where $A,B$ are real and $A^2=B^2=I$. The aforementioned answer by Omnomnomnom has actually given a unified constructive example that takes care of all possible cases, but I'll construct two examples here, one for a real spectrum and one for a nonreal spectrum.

For any nonzero real number $x$, consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&x\\ \frac1x&0},\ B=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}.
$$
For any nonzero nonreal number $z=e^{i\theta}$, let $R_{\theta/2}$ be the $2\times2$ rotation matrix for angle $\frac\theta2$. Now we may consider
$$
A=R_{\theta/2}\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}R_{\theta/2}^T
\text{ and } B=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0},
$$
so that $\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}R_{\theta/2}^T\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}=R_{\theta/2}$ and $AB=R_\theta$.